# Animating UIView alpha according to views location

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am animating a view using this code but would like to set the alpha of the orb according to its location . is this possible as I understand that the animation block is executed immediately and I have no access to its location

```
self.orbView.center = self.arrowView.center;
    self.orbView.alpha = 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        self.orbView.center = CGPointMake(arrowCornerRight,self.orbView.center.y);
        self.orbView.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
```

Comment: This should have the desired effect: move to the CGPoint and set alpha to 0 in one second and back, repeating. Did you try it?

Comment: The code seems like correct...whats the problem then ?

Comment: after setting the new center in the animation block you have access to the orbView's new frame because it's being set immediately and the animation is done in a seperate presentationLayer. so in the next line you could do your alpha calculation depending on the new position and set the orbView's alpha accordingly.